# Other types of mean error

Tags: error, approximation

Let $\tilde f$ be an approximation of the function $f(x) = \arccos(x)$. I'm using MATLAB to figure out how good this approximation is by calculating a mean error. My first idea was to use this formula : $$err =\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (f(n) -\tilde f(n))^2}$$

My problem with this formula is that the error is pretty low for $\tilde f$ functions that are close to $f$ overall but that are not necessarily close at some points like lets say for example near the extremes (at $x=\pm1$), which is not what I want. I would prefer to have 3° of error pretty much everywhere rather than 1° overall and 5° at few points.

**My question** : is there an other formula for the mean error such that :

- the lower the error, the more $|f(n) -\tilde f(n)|$ is closed to being constant everywhere
- the lower the error, the lower $|f(n) -\tilde f(n)|$ is overall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the concept of [$p$-norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions) helpful. Your metric, which is analogous to [root mean square error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) in statistics, is the $p$-norm with $p = 2$. As $p$ increases, the $p$-norm, considered as a metric, cares more about the few largest deviations and less about the average deviation overall. The $p$-norm for $p = ∞$ is called the "sup norm", "max norm", or "uniform norm", and in this context, it would be calculated as

$\max
\limits_n |f(n) - \tilde f(n)| \quad .$

Perhaps that would work well for your purposes.